# How to break the page in dompdf?

Tags: php, css, laravel, dompdf

I'm currently working with Laravel and utilizing the dompdf library. I'm facing an issue regarding page breaks when the content exceeds a certain number of characters. You can see the problem in this image:
[image: page]
At the moment, I would like to implement page breaks in dompdf. Here's the code snippet where I want the page break to occur:

```
<table class="table-no-border">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 14px;"><b>IMÓVEL OU DIREITO REAL OUTORGADO</b></p>
                    @if($endereco)
                        <p>LOTE {{$endereco->lote}} - QUADRA {{$endereco->quadra}}, MATRÍCULA @if(isset($matricula)) {{$matricula}} @endif, situado no município de {{$config->cidade}}, localizado na {{$endereco->tipo_logradouro}} {{$endereco->logradouro}}, nº {{$endereco->numero}} - {{$endereco->bairro}}, {{$endereco->cidade}} - {{$endereco->estado}}, {{$endereco->cep}}, com as seguintes medidas e confrontações: Área: {{$lote->lote_area}}m². Perímetro: {{$lote->lote_perimetro}}m. <br> {{trim(strip_tags($lote->memorial_descritivo))}}.
                        <!-- <div class="page-break"></div> -->
                        Atribui-se ao imóvel o valor de R$ {{$lote->lote_valor}} <b>({{$valor_extenso}})</b>.</p>
                    @endif
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I have attempted to use a div with the class 'page-break', and it does work. However, I need the page break to occur automatically whenever the text exceeds the page length. Is there anyone who can assist me?

```
.page-break {
            page-break-after: always;
        }
```

My dompdf config:

```
$pdf_merge = new PDFMerger;

            $html = view('versa.titulo-legitimacao.visualizar-titulo-individual', $dados)->render();

            $dompdf = new Dompdf();
            $dompdf->set_option('enable_html5_parser', TRUE);
            $dompdf->getOptions()->getChroot();
            $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
            $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
            $dompdf->render();
            $output = $dompdf->output();
            $filePath = storage_path() . "/" .getInstancia()."/titulo-legitimacao-".$user->id."/titulo-legitimacao-individual-".$lote->lote_codigo.".pdf";
            file_put_contents($filePath, $output);
```

Comment: By default it should break once the page limit is reached. We might need to see your `dompdf` config to learn more about the issue.

Comment: this is my dompdf config:
```
$pdf_merge = new PDFMerger;
$html = view('versa.titulo-legitimacao.visualizar-titulo-individual', $dados)->render();
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->set_option('enable_html5_parser', TRUE);
$dompdf->getOptions()->getChroot();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$output = $dompdf->output();
$filePath = storage_path() . "/" .getInstancia()."/titulo-legitimacao-".$user->id."/titulo-legitimacao-individual-".$lote->lote_codigo.".pdf";
file_put_contents($filePath, $output);
```

Comment: Please update your question and include your config there.

Comment: Ok. I added the config there

Answer (score 1):

It seems your text is as long as shown *within*  a block element/container, so you should use `break-inside: auto;` for the element/s that contain the text.

Comment: I have a div called main and the body. I tried to use body{ break-inside: auto;} and .main{break-inside: auto;} and does it not working.

Comment: In your code there's are some table elements and a `p` tag, so I am pretty sure the text isn't directly in the `body` tag, but in another tag/element to which this setting would need to be applied. Use the browser tools inside the print preview to find which element contains the text.

Comment: You can check the code in this link:

https://codefile.io/f/0JbJWvrRg4